# Telnet and shell scripting. maintain session open and send data while the script is in execution

Tags: linux, shell-script, telnet

I want to send two or more messages to a TCP server using telnet client from bash.
This implies that I should maintain the session open while my script is in execution.

For example, the script flow should be:

```
1) open telnet session
2) send 1st message
3) sleep 1 s
4) send 2nd message
5) close session
```

What is the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

`expect` is the best tool for such usage cases. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630242/need-to-run-remote-command-over-ssh-with-a-pause-before-sending-remote-command/630256#630256) is my answer to a similar question as yours on Unix & Linux site. It can be simply adapted to your case:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet 10.0.0.1
expect "ogin:"
send "myuser\r"
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
expect "#"
send "command1\r"
expect "#"
sleep 1
send "command2\r"
expect "#"
send "exit\r"
```